# Python socket errno 111

Tags: python, sockets, connection

so when I run

```
import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 8088))
s.listen(10)
while 1:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print c, addr
    c.send('hello')
    c.close()
s.shutdown()
```

and

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
while 1:
    print s.recv(2048)
```

I get errno 111 connection refused. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> s.bind(('', 8088))

You bind on port 8088

> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))

But attempt to connect to port 8080.

Note that 8088 (bind) is not the same as 8080 (connect) and that's why the connect fails, i.e. *connection refused*.